# Combining views programmatically - Android

Tags: android, view

I've got a list of layouts that I need displayed on a PDF. However I'd like to find a way where I can combine these views into one view.

```
for(LinearLayout cardView : selectedCardIDList){
            pageNo++;
            cardView.measure(measuredWidth, 0);
            cardView.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, cardView.getHeight());
            cardView.draw(canvas);
        }
```

This is the method I use to draw each view. I'd like to combine the views and then draw the new view.

[image: View Example]

Here's a quick example i drew up with 'V' being View.

On the left I have View 1 and View 2, I'd to try and stack them in a brand new view like View 3. Hope this helps

Here is an example of my problem.
[image: Here is an example of my problem.]

```
private void generatePDF(){
            PrintAttributes printAttributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                    .setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
                    .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
                    .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS)
                    .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("Res_Test", PRINT_SERVICE, 450, 700))
                    .build();

            PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(getActivity(), printAttributes);

            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595,842,1).create();

            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

            for(LinearLayout cardView : selectedCardIDList){
        ((ViewGroup)cardView.getParent()).removeView(cardView);
        combiPDfView.addView(cardView);
    }
    combiPDfView.draw(canvas);

            document.finishPage(page);
    }
```

This is the method I'm using to generate the PDF.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

This is the layout that I've made to add views to and display on the PDF.
combiPDfView is the name of the LinearLayout.

Comment: Can you post the view what exactly you want to implement...

Comment: @Sunny Added an example, Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by using this:

Take a parent Linearlayout with the orientation vertical

```
LinearLayout parentView= findViewById(R.id.parentView);
```

**code to add the view**

```
for(LinearLayout cardView : selectedCardIDList){
            // View to be added
            pageNo++;
            cardView.measure(measuredWidth, 0);
            cardView.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, cardView.getHeight());
            cardView.draw(canvas);
            //add view to parent view
            parentView.addView(cardView);
        }
```

Comment: This is producing the same effect as my previous attempts, where all the views are stacking instead of going beneath each other. I did have to call `((ViewGroup)cardView.getParent()).removeView(cardView);` because calling it with a parent attached threw an error.

Comment: What do you mean "stacking instead of going beneath"? Not aligned? Overlap? Aslo, do you really need to do this in code? Or in xml is also fine?

Comment: @user1209216 I've added a new image showing my issue. The UI has about 6 card views on it, the user is able to select from these card views, this is how the list is generated, and from that list I generate the PDF. So I thought doing it from code would probably be best.

Comment: can you share java file you have tried so far and the exact view you want to display in the pdf? So, I can share demo code as per your need.

Comment: @Sunny I've added my method i'm using, this is the one I've modified with your suggestion.

Comment: I've added `combiPDfView.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);` And it seemed to fixed my issue. Going to do some more testing to confirm

Comment: Yeah this solution did the trick, definitely put me on the right track, thank you.